# How to execute laravel job at low priority?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

We have multiple jobs in our laravel application. Currently all jobs are queued at once and they execute one by one. I want this particular job to execute at low priority it means if anyother job comes after that job should be execute first.

```
BulkPdfPrintLabel::withChain([
                    new MergeLabel($filepath, $manifest_id, $last, $user_id, $user_type)
                ])->dispatch($consignments, $last, $manifest_id, $user_id, $user_type, $filepath);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead:

```
// This job is sent to the default queue that you selected in config/app file
BulkPdfPrintLabel::withChain([
                    new MergeLabel($filepath, $manifest_id, $last, $user_id, $user_type)])
          ->dispatch($consignments, $last, $manifest_id, $user_id, $user_type, $filepath);
```

**update**

```
// This job is sent to the "low" queue.("low" is custom and you can change it)
BulkPdfPrintLabel::withChain([
                    new MergeLabel($filepath, $manifest_id, $last, $user_id, $user_type)->onQueue("low")
                ])
        ->dispatch($consignments, $last, $manifest_id, $user_id, $user_type, $filepath);
```

then run this command to set high priority to your default queue:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default
```

reference [laravel queue](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#connections-vs-queues)

Comment: i am using supervisor on live server which is running ```php artisan queue:work``` do i need to replace it with ```php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default```

Comment: giving this error ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingChain::onQueue()```